# Lucene.net searching: return results with unique field value

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I'm writing a basic Lucene.Net application to index what are essentially forum posts. To simplify, each `Post` document has a `URL` and some `Content`. For each given thread I'm indexing each `Post` as a separate document (indexing whole threads as single documents returns too many false positives when searching).

The problem I'm having is dealing with multiple `Post` documents having the same `URL` in my results sets. When I search and return 10 results, I want each result to refer to a different `URL`.

Currently, I have something along the lines of the following:

```
// setup
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
FSDirectory directory = FSDirectory.Open(indexLocation);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);
parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "body", analyzer);

// search
Query query = parser.Parse(queryString);
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search(query, null, 10);
```

However, of the ten results returned, there may only be 7 unique `URLs`. I've looked at discarding these duplicates before searching again, returning a larger results set and discarding the first 10 (similar to pagination) until I have 10 unique `URLs`, but this raises questions such as when should I stop because there are no more results? etc.

It feels like there should be a way of filtering at the `TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search()` point, to return 10 results which have unique `URLs`. I can't find anything around this (perhaps I'm not using the correct terminology) but I'm sure a lot of other applications must have solved this before... Does anything like this already exist, or can anyone offer pointers as to how to go about implementing this?

Comment: You can write your own *HitCollector*

Comment: It seems you want each result to represent a different forum thread, then basically your results yield URLs, not posts. As @L.B notes you can subclass `HitCollector` to do this, perhaps with a helper `HashSet` object to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: Hello Matthew, our team is also having trouble on this.. did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not!

Answer (score 0):

i have developed such functionlaity as extra filter for lucene 2.9.x
and right now i have found that it shouldb e rewritten fully for 4.8

so in case when you are using 2.9.x version there is solution:
your own  hit collector, in method collect should also check that document is in unique documents documents set (bit array). bit array has to be constructed ones and cached (source):

```html
public class DistinctValuesFilter
{
    #region ctor
    public DistinctValuesFilter(IndexReader searchReader, ISearchRequest request, int docLength, Analyzer anlzr)
    {
        this.distinctBy = StringHelper.Intern(request.DistinctBy);
        this.processedMask = new OpenBitSetDISI(docLength);
        FindDuplicateTermsDirectly(searchReader);
        iireader = searchReader;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// initialize: duplicates hashset and array of possitions where duplicates are situated
    /// code partially has been takend from lucene: Lucene.Net.Search.FieldCacheImpl.StringIndexCache       
    /// protected internal override object CreateValue(IndexReader reader, Entry entryKey)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ireader">index reader to process duplicates</param>
    private void FindDuplicateTermsDirectly(IndexReader ireader)
    {
        var maxlemgth = ireader.MaxDoc();
        duplicates = new HashSet<int>(maxlemgth);
        duplicatesLocations = new int[maxlemgth];
        var termEnum = ireader.Terms(new Term(this.distinctBy));
        var termDocs = ireader.TermDocs();
        int num = 0;
        int k, p;
        int firstDocNo = -1;

        try
        {
            do
            {
                var term = termEnum.Term();
                if (term == null || term.Field() != this.distinctBy || num >= maxlemgth)
                    break;
                termDocs.Seek(termEnum);
                p = 0;
                while (termDocs.Next())
                {
                    k = termDocs.Doc();
                    duplicatesLocations[k] = num + 1;//0- needs to indicate that records/document completelly empty
                    if (p > 0) duplicates.Add(firstDocNo);
                    firstDocNo = k;
                    p++;
                }
                if (p > 1) duplicates.Add(firstDocNo);
                num++;
            }
            while (termEnum.Next());
        }
        finally
        {
            termDocs.Close();
            termEnum.Close();
        }
    }

    protected IndexReader iireader;
    protected string distinctBy;

    private HashSet<int> duplicates;
    private int[] duplicatesLocations;
    private OpenBitSetDISI processedMask;


    #endregion
    private Lazy<string[]> ivalue => new Lazy<string[]>(() => FieldCache_Fields.DEFAULT.GetStrings(iireader, distinctBy));
    public bool IsDistinct(int docIndex)
    {
        if (this.processedMask.FastGet(docIndex)) return false;
        if (duplicatesLocations[docIndex] == 0) return false;//when value doesn't exist completelly
        if (!duplicates.Contains(docIndex)) return true;
        var dval = duplicatesLocations[docIndex];
        var v = ivalue.Value;
        var xv = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < duplicatesLocations.Length; i++)
        {
            if (duplicatesLocations[i] == dval)
            {
                this.processedMask.FastSet(i);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xv) && xv != v[i])
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException($"values are not same ({i}): [{xv}] != [{v[i]}]");
                }
                xv = v[i];
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: for 4.8 found one schema:
    - own collector (as wrapper for existing lucene)
    - in setnextreader : process all internal terms in atomic reader (issue that couple of readers can share own not unique terms)
    - during collect - check that document terms are not in the list those are processed already 
 (complete varinat i am gonig to add in next comment)